# What does a sudo command do?

Tags: sudo

What does this command do?

```
$sudo /usr/bin/su -something
```

Is `-something` a password or username for running commands under this username?

Comment: What flavor of *nix are you using? http://linux.die.net/man/8/sudo

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of `sudo` is to execute the command given to it with root privileges.

The purpose of `su` is to switch the current user context. It is basically a precursor to sudo. If no user name is specified for su, then it switches to root.

Exactly what su will do depends on the value of `-something`. You can get some guidance by looking at `man su`.

`sudo su` on its own is a fairly common trick to drop to a root shell, if for some reason `sudo -i` isn't available.

Comment: Beat me to it. Just to clarify, `-something` would need to be something along the lines of `-s/bin/sh` (`/bin/sh` can be any program). `su` can handle its own authentication, but it requires that you have the password of the user you are switching to. `sudo` is used because it allows you to authenticate with the password of your own user or no password, depending on how `sudo` is configured.

Comment: You'll probably see `sudo` used with the `-s` flag as well. The `-s` flag will start your own user's login shell as the superuser (root), while the `-i` flag will start the superuser's login shell.

Comment: @EvanTeitelman I'm pretty sure `su -something` is invalid, though, so the real answer to the question still depends on the exact command line.

Comment: I was just explaining that `-something` would need to be a different argument. (`-s/bin/sh` would be valid, for example.)

Answer (score 1):

`/usr/bin/su` is the command being run. **-something** is a parameter being passed to that command.

There has to be a matching regex in /etc/sudoers allowing that command and that parameter.